# Converting 64 word (clk/8) to 8x8 word (clk) (Digital Design - Verilog)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I need to make some sort of interface between my PS and PL on Zynq chip. I need block which will accept 64bit long word (at every clk/8) and send 8 by 8bit word at the output (on every clk). So basically I need to divide 64 bit word into 8 x 8bits word. If you have advice's how to do it please share.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register the 64 bits data at the clock when it is ready. Then do the left/right shift 8 bits (depends on your endian requirement) for the following 7 cycles. Your 8 MSBs/LSBs will be your output data respectively.